# La descarga de react desde consola no termina

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows10, instalacion

Estoy instalando react js en mi computadora(windows 10) todo desde la consola de windows, ejecuto los siguientes comandos:

C:\Users\HP>cd desktop

C:\Users\HP\Desktop>npx create-react-app miapp

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\miapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\HP\Desktop\miapp\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

core-js@3.7.0 postinstall C:\Users\HP\Desktop\miapp\node_modules\core-js node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

core-js-pure@3.7.0 postinstall C:\Users\HP\Desktop\miapp\node_modules\core-js-pure node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\HP\Desktop\miapp\node_modules\ejs node ./postinstall.js

cra-template@1.1.0
react@17.0.1
react-scripts@4.0.0
react-dom@17.0.1 added 1925 packages from 738 contributors and audited 1929 packages in 1016.312s
119 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Segun documentacion deberia seguir la descarga, cosa que no pasa y se mantiene por horas congelado :c

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la instalación de *ReactJS* vamos a seguir estos sencillos pasos:

**Paso 1.** Instalar NodeJS en su ultima versión, para eso entraremos a su web oficial y descargaremos el instalador más actualizado https://nodejs.org/es/

**Paso 2.** Actualizar NPM, el gestor de paquetes de node, para bajarnos las dependencias más actuales:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

**Paso 3.** Borrar la cache de NPM:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**Paso 4.** Instalar Create React App, que es un interprete de consola(CLI) que nos va a permitir instalar React fácilmente e incluirá webpack para la compilación y minificación del proyecto, un live reload, una estructura básica para los proyectos de ReactJS, etc, veamos como instalar este paquete:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Ahora ya tenemos instalado «create react app» y ya podemos generar un nuevo proyecto de React.js

Para generar un nuevo proyecto de React.js y finalmente instalarlo, entraremos al directorio donde queramos generar el proyecto de reactjs y ejecutamos este comando:

```
create-react-app NombreDeMiProyecto
```

Ahora entraremos al directorio de nuestro proyecto y lanzaremos el servidor local de pruebas para React:

```
cd NombreDeMiProyecto
npm start
```

Puedes comprobar la versión de React que tienes dentro del fichero package.json.

Ahora tendremos disponible la webapp de React 16 en `http://localhost:3000/` y veremos nuestro proyecto corriendo, con la página de bienvenida por defecto.

Con esto ya sabemos como instalar React desde cero y como generar un proyecto base.

Comment: guiate con estos pasos

Comment: Hola!, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, seguí los pasos y paso varias partes, pero sigue quedandosé en un punto dado